# Merging a list of PNG and JPG images into a video is not working

Tags: ffmpeg, merge, png

I'm trying to merge a list of images ***JPG and PNG (contains transparent area)*** following the rules below:

- If the image is a ***PNG***, it should be drawn over the previous JPG image.
- If the image is a ***JPG***, it should be merged without any changes, and the merging process should continue.

I'm using the below command, it's working fine if all images are JPG, but it's not working with ***PNG (contains transparent area)*** images :

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -i frames.txt -vf fps=30 -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

**frames.txt**

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file photos/photo1.jpg
duration 3
file photos/photo1.jpg
file photos/photo2.png
duration 3
file photos/photo2.png
file photos/photo3.jpg
duration 3
file photos/photo3.jpg
file photos/photo4.jpg
duration 3
file photos/photo4.jpg
file photos/photo5.jpg
duration 3
file photos/photo5.jpg
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-1 → All files must have the same streams (same codecs, same time base, etc.).